# Appending instances of a class to a list overrides previous instance attributes

Tags: python, class, object, instance

So i'm trying to generate a list of class objects using nested while loops. I have two types of classes, normal_class and special_class.

For special_class, I give it x, y coordinates by doing special_class.set(x,y). For the normal class, I just leave it as it is.

If I append another special_class by doing special_class.set(x,y), and then ls.append(special_class) it overrides the coordinates of the first, so I end up with two special_class with the same coordinates instead of two special_class with separate coordinates.

I've only recently started programming in Python so any help would be helpful :)

This is some pseudo code:

1. Input is a string of characters ie. "XXY"
2. I compare each of these characters to a dictionary I've created ie. dict = { "X": special_class(), "Y": normal_class}
3. I want to set the coordinates of special_class, normal_class doesn't have coordinate attributes
4. If character_from_string == key from dictionary, check if it's a special or normal class. Then use the value pair
5. If it's a special class, set_pos(x,y) for some numbers x,y. If it's normal, pass
6. Append the class instance to the list
7. So i'd hope for an output such as [special_class object, special_class object, normal_class object]
8. If I do ls[0].get_pos, and ls[1].get_pos, it returns the same value, even if I set it to different x,y. Why? And how can I fix this?

Code!

```py
class special_class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.char = "X"
    def set_pos(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def get_pos(self):
        return (self.x, self.y)


class normal_class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.char = "Y"

class also_special_class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.char = "Z"
    def set_pos(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def get_pos(self):
        return (self.x, self.y)



string = "XYXZ"
dict = {"X": special_class(), "Y": normal_class(), "Z": also_special_class()}
ls = []

i = 0
while i < len(string):
    k = 0
    keys = list(dict.keys())
    while k < len(keys):
        if string[i] == keys[k]:
            instance = dict[keys[k]]
            if keys[k] == "X" or keys[k] =="Z": # i and k numbers that change
                special_class = instance.set_pos(i, k) # why is special_class None?
                ### this code is ugly but it's the only way I know of doing it without errors
                ### however, the position of the two elements is not what I put into it initially

                special_instance = dict[keys[k]]
                special_instance.set_pos(i,k)
                print(special_instance.get_pos())
                instance = special_instance
            ls.append(instance)
        k += 1

    i += 1

print()
print(ls)
print("\nPosition after finished loop")
print(ls[0].get_pos())
print(ls[2].get_pos())
```

If you could give me pointers as to
a) why is that commented piece of special_class returning None
b) Giving pointers as to improving my code, especially this part

```py
special_instance = dict[keys[k]]
                special_instance.set_pos(i,k)
                print(special_instance.get_pos())
                instance = special_instance
```

c) Explaining why I'm getting the same values for get_pos and how I can fix my code so that it works as intended, that'd be amazing!!

Comment: "This is some pseudo code:" I'm sorry, but if you are requesting debugging help, then you *must* provide a [mcve]

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Comment: @Sov Please post your code so that we can understand the problem. For more info - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Okay, i'm writing it up now :) I'll let you knwo when ot's done

Comment: Done! It would be great if you could explain to me what is happened and if there are any ways of making the code less ugly.

Comment: You keep re-using the same instances, you've only created two, the ones you put in your `dict`

Comment: As an aside, stop using `while` loops here, use for-loops.

Comment: Ah okay, so how do I fix the fact that I keep using the same instances ? And yeah, I'll start using for loops more regularly from now on

Comment: @Sov keep your current dict approach,  but *put the classes themselves in the dict*, not instances, which is what happens when you *call the class* so `class_map = {'X':FirstClass, 'Y': SecondClass}` instead of `class_map = {'X': FirstClass(), 'Y': SecondClass()}`. Then when you use the dict, do something like `special_instance = class_map[keys[k]]()`

Comment: Thank you juanpa!! This exactly the solution I was looking for, fixed all my problems and made my code better, i'll add the corrected code into the body of my question

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to make a non-shallow copy of the class object. This will add the class object (`kls`) and not a reference to it.

Specifically, in your case, doing this should fix the problem.

```py
from copy import deepcopy
ls.append(deepcopy(special_class))
```

### Example

```py
from copy import deepcopy

klasses = []

for _ in range(5):
    #initialize the class object
    kls = YourClass() 
    klasses.append(deepcopy(kls))
```

### Some suggestions for your class definitions:

1. Class names must be `CamelCased`. See python class/variable/functions/methods naming convention [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id41) for more details.

   ```py
   # example
   class SpecialClass(object):
       def __init__(self):
           ...

       def some_method(self):
           ...
   ```
2. Instantiate the class with parenthesis at least; and if necessary, with arguments, as required by the `__init__()` method. For example, `kls = SpecialClass` only creates an alias to the class, `SpecialClass` by the name `kls` and does not instantiate `SpecialClass`. To instantiate use: `SpecialClass()` instead.

   ```py
   # example
   kls = SpecialClass()
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the help!! Is there any way I can do this without importing a module?

Comment: The `copy` module is part of pure python. So, just import it. https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy

Comment: Since you create your class instance inside a loop, I assume that it is being saved to a variable. This is where you must use deepcopy. However, if you directly did this: `ls.append(Special_Class())` that would not require any deepcopy.

Comment: @Sov updated the solution with some extra points about yor class definitions. Please take a look at it.

Comment: `classes` and `cls` are not great names for instances. They are generally used for class objects, not their instances. It's confusing.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, I agree with you. I did that to quickly answer back then. But I will change them to something else.

Comment: Thank you so much for the in-depth answer! I didn't realise the difference in instantiating classes but now I do :)

Comment: @Sov I'm glad that it helped. Please consider **`accepting`** and **`up-voting`** the answer.